# Worksheet doesn't exist?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to open a workbook from MS Access. This is what I am using and I keep getting a

> runtime error 9 "subscript out of range" error.

I thought this error was only when you try to set an object that doesn't exist, but the worksheet "Raw Data" exists for Workbook1. Does anyone know that else could cause this error? Thanks

```
Dim appxls As Excel.application
Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook
Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet

Set appxls = New Excel.application
Set wkb = appxls.Workbooks.Open("C:\Workbook1.xlsm")
Set wks = wkb.Sheets("Raw Data")          --- Error Line
```

Edit:

The code will open the file the correct file, but when I print the names of the worksheets this is what I get. I'm confused because none of these worksheets exist in the file that is opened from appxls.Workbooks.Open

```
Worksheet(1) - Language
Worksheet(2) - Report
Worksheet(3) - 1028
Worksheet(4) - 1029
Worksheet(5) - 1030
```

Edit 2:

I figured out the cause of the error. When I add a reference to "Solver", it causes this error. But when I remove the reference, it works fine. Somehow adding the reference to "Solver" is causing the workbook to change or something but I am not sure how to fix.

Comment: Check for trailing spaces... that error means that no worksheet with the name `Raw Data` exists in that workbook.

Comment: @BigBen I tried that and copy paste the worksheet name from excel into the code

Comment: There is no other reason that that line would fail.

Comment: Try `wkb.WorkSheets("Raw Data")` instead... and also keep in mind that sometimes there is a leading or trailing space in the worksheet name that can cause this error. A lot of people don't really notice that extra space, but it makes all the difference.

Comment: is it the first workbook? You can also try `wkb.Worksheets(1)` - also, try adding (before it) `Debug.Print "|" & wkb.Worksheets(1).Name & "|"` and see what that returns.

Comment: I figured out a few things. See edits.